# Add text in word based on content

Tags: python, vba

I have a batch of .doc documents, in the first line of each document I have the name of a person written. I would like to add in each document the email adress of the person, based on a list I have. How can I use python or vba to program something that does the job for me?

I tried to do this vba code, that finds the name of the person and then writes the email, was thinking to loop it over. However even this minumum working example does not actually work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Sub email()
    Selection.find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    If Selection.find.Text = "Chiara Gatta" Then
       With Selection.find
        .Text = "E-mail:"
        .Replacement.Text = "E-mail: chiara.gatta@gmail.com"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
       End With
    Selection.find.Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I tried to look at what other have written but nothing seems to work for me, or the questions already asked do not seem to apply properly to my case, so I started wondering if maybe what I am aiming for is just impossible with either python or vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question lacks minimum details & code required for help. However I am trying to give you a code that would pickup person names & email addresses from one table in a document containing the code. the table should have 3 columns, 1st col contain Name of the person, 2nd col should contain Email address with 3rd column blank for remarks from code. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOXcC.jpg)

On running the code you would be prompted to select the word files that would be replaced by the email address. On trial use only copy files and may try only a handful of files at a time (if file sizes are large). It is assumed that files will contain Name and  word “E-mail:”  (if "E-mail:" word is not in the file try to modify the code as commented)

Code:

```
Sub test2()
Dim Fldg As FileDialog, Fl As Variant
Dim Thdoc As Document, Edoc As Document
Dim Tbl As Table, Rw As Long, Fnd As Boolean
Dim xName As String, xEmail As String

Set Thdoc = ThisDocument
Set Tbl = Thdoc.Tables(1)
    Set Fldg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With Fldg
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Word Documents ", "*.doc,*.dot,*docx,*.docm,*.dotm", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "C:\users\user\desktop\folder1\*.doc*" 'use your choice of folder
     If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    End With

    'Search for each Name in  Table 1 column 1
    For Rw = 1 To Tbl.Rows.Count
    xName = Tbl.Cell(Rw, 1).Range.Text
    xEmail = Tbl.Cell(Rw, 2).Range.Text
        If Len(xName) > 2 And Len(xEmail) > 2 Then
        xName = Left(xName, Len(xName) - 2)        'Clean special characters in word cell text
        xEmail = Left(xEmail, Len(xEmail) - 2)     'Clean special characters in word cell text

           'open each Document selected & search for names
            For Each Fl In Fldg.SelectedItems
            Set Edoc = Documents.Open(Fl)
            Fnd = False
                With Edoc.Content.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = xName
                .Replacement.Text = xName & vbCrLf & "E-mail: " & xEmail
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceNone
                '.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
                Fnd = .Found
                End With

                'if Word "E-mail is not already in the file, delete next if Fnd Branch"
                ' And use .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne instead of .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceNone
                If Fnd Then  ' If Name is found then Search for "E-Mail:"
                Fnd = False
                With Edoc.Content.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Text = "E-mail:"
                .Replacement.Text = "E-mail: " & xEmail
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
                Fnd = .Found
                End With
                End If

                If Fnd Then
                Edoc.Save
                Tbl.Cell(Rw, 3).Range.Text = "Found & Replaced in  " & Fl
                Exit For
                Else
                Tbl.Cell(Rw, 3).Range.Text = "Not found in any selected document"
                End If
            Edoc.Close False
            Next Fl
       End If
    Next Rw
End Sub
```

it's operation would be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUWT5.gif). Try to understand each action in the code and modify to your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help! This looks very close to what I am looking for. I have made a table in a word file, similar to the one in your picture and tried to run the code in the vba, keeping the file with the table open. However I get an error at thi point:           Set Tbl = Thdoc.Tables(1)                 (Error 5941)   I guess the error depends on the fact that the code does not recognize the open document as active, and thus cannot find the table I have produced. I am trying so solve the issue but if you have any idea I would be extremely grateful. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I had not put the module of the macro in the right folder!  Now it seems going smooth. Thank you so so much! I hope your answer can benefit also other people.